# Delete all Twitter DMs at once

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message

I have been looking around for a while now and it seems that all the ways to delete your direct messages on Twitter at once are outdated and do not work anymore. I was just wondering if anyone had found a current solution on how to delete all direct messages on Twitter at once.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no official way to delete all direct messages at once. You have to use some third party apps.

You can give a try to this app [Twitter DM Cleaner](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/dm-cleaner). The app will ask for access to your DMs.